# Which tropical evergreen trees shed the maximum amount of foliage year-round?

Tags: agriculture, plant

I want to use the foliage to create compost for my farm.
What are the maximum foliage shedding tropical evergreen trees ?

Comment: Are you only interested in maximum foliage?  Some plants are not great for composting even though they grow quickly.

Comment: Lets just say i want to increase humus/carbon content in the soil.

Comment: You might find something here https://www.gardeningchannel.com/top-fast-growing-trees/